# Trying to print out only "state failed" but Python is printing everything

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looping through the HTML content of a web page and trying to print only strings with the substring "state failed".  However, Python is printing every single string, even the ones that don't have the substring "state failed".

Here is my code:

```
soup = bs(html_page, 'lxml')
outF = open('C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/test.csv', 'w')
for link in soup.findAll('rect'):
    if "state failed" in link:
        if link.isoweekday() in range(1, 6):
            outF.write(str(link))
            outF.write('\n')   
outF.close()
```

Here is one that I would expect to be printed, and it is.

```
<rect class="state failed" data-original-title="Task_id: failure_cleanup&lt;br&gt;Run: 2018-12-22T04:00:00&lt;br&gt;Operator: CruxCleanupOperator&lt;br&gt;Started: 2018-12-24T18:34:39.149434&lt;br&gt;Ended: 2018-12-24T18:34:45.935977&lt;br&gt;Duration: 6.78654&lt;br&gt;State: failed&lt;br&gt;" data-toggle="tooltip" height="10" rx="0" ry="0" style="shape-rendering: crispedges; stroke-width: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" title="" width="10" x="984" y="-5"></rect>
```

Here is one that I would expect NOT to be printed, but form some odd reason it is being printed.

```
<rect class="state success" data-original-title="Task_id: join_cleanup&lt;br&gt;Run: 2018-12-22T04:00:00&lt;br&gt;Operator: CompletionBranchOperator&lt;br&gt;Started: 2018-12-24T18:33:30.834983&lt;br&gt;Ended: 2018-12-24T18:33:33.037330&lt;br&gt;Duration: 2.20235&lt;br&gt;State: success&lt;br&gt;" data-toggle="tooltip" height="10" rx="0" ry="0" style="shape-rendering: crispedges; stroke-width: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" title="" width="10" x="984" y="-5"></rect>
```

I tied all combinations with the single quotes, double, and even triple.  It dodesn't matter.  It prints everything, even the strings that don't contain "State failed".  Any idea what's wrong here?  Thanks.

Comment: Are ya doing this? `'state success' in s`, can you please show us the code?

Comment: Whoops!  I actually forgot to post my code.  Ok, I just updated y original post.

Comment: What is the result of `print(link)` if you put it the line before the if statement, in the loop?

Comment: And also if you make it: `print(type(link))`

Comment: The print(link) statement print this: <rect class="state success"...etc.,  The print(type(link)), prints this: <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>

Comment: Saw my answer?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try making the `link` into a string:

```
soup = bs(html_page, 'lxml')
outF = open('C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/test.csv', 'w')
for link in soup.findAll('rect'):
    if "state failed" in str(link):
        if link.isoweekday() in range(1, 6):
            outF.write(str(link))
            outF.write('\n')   
outF.close()
```

Then it should work.

Comment: Yeap, yeap, converting it to a string worked!  Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: @ryguy72 Happy to help, :-), 

Comment: Happy Holidays to you!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if "state failed" in link:`, replace it with `if "state failed" is link.get('class')` or `if "state failed" == link.get('class')`. I think you better go with `is`, since you may get `None` for `link.get('class')` is `class` attribute is not there.

You can also do it this way:

```
soup = bs(html_page, 'lxml')
outF = open('C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/test.csv', 'w')
for link in soup.findAll('rect', attrs={'class': 'state failed'}):
    if link.isoweekday() in range(1, 6):
        outF.write(str(link))
        outF.write('\n')   
outF.close()
```

[Source](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)